# Pentaho:-CSV file input

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am very new to Pentaho DI.
My requirement:-
In my CSV file input step, I don't want to select files from browser. I want to pass it through variable or dynamic way.

Let say. I have file in "Download" Folder and daily file names get change.
So,in CSV file input step, if i pass variable and set file name of "Download" folder in this variable then each time, I don't have to browse file manually.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression in text-file input step.
design a transformation in a way that once the process will completes it will delete the old file.
so everytime when you execute your job it will take the new file from specific folder.

Comment: @NileshPatil you can accept the answer as a solution.